# javascript or jquery to change innerHTML of a div?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, ajax

This function allow me to load a webform/popup above my page test.aspx

```
  $(document).ready(function () {
  $('#<%= webform.ClientID %>').load('pop_up_one.html');})
```

I now would like to change the innerhtml of this popup with 
another popup and have the possibility to come back to the first
popup. Basicly I just want to change the innerhtml of the DIV of the
first pop_up

How is possible to do that? thought adding something like:

```
   $('#div_of_popup_one').click.load('pop_up_two.html');
```

but this does not work.

The only way I found to make it work has been to integrate this code
into pop_up_1-html:

```
    function loadextPage(event) {
        var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function () {
            if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
                document.getElementById('name_of_div_to_change').innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
            }
        }
        xmlhttp.open("GET", event.target.href, true);
        xmlhttp.send();
    }
```

and call this  from:

Go to second pop up

This method works but i would like to do it with something like

```
        $('#div_of_popup_one').click.load('pop_up_two.html')
```

from the page i am calling the pop_up_one

Comment: Do you mean: ``$('#div_of_popup_one').click(function () { $(this).load('pop_up_two.html'); });``

Comment: hi, your solution is working but the problem is that I have different DIV inside a MAIN-DIV so your code will change only the div you click into. Is possible to click on the div interessed but change the entire one.

Comment: Fixit. Instead of using  $(this), I used the MAIN_DIV :-) thank you

Comment: Oh, finally understood what you meant, good job XD

Comment: Sorry for m bad way of explaining. thank you so far

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To do this, first you need to, bind `click` event and then invoke `click`. Use the following code.

```
   $('#div_of_popup_one').on("click", function() {
       $(this).load('pop_up_two.html');
   });

   $('#div_of_popup_one').click();
```

Comment: Yes, it is, to bind `"click"` event for required `div`.

Comment: Hey, that solution it does not work for me, i cannot understand why

Comment: No error, just when i click nothing happen. I am trying different solution. thank you